In equation (3) from lecture 7 in Leonard Susskind’s ‘Classical Mechanics’, should the derivatives be partial?
Here are the equations. ($V$ represents a potential function and $p$ represents momentum.)
$$V(q_1,q_2) = V(aq_1 - bq_2)$$
$$\dot{p}_1 = -aV'(aq_1 - bq_2)$$
$$\dot{p}_2 = +bV'(aq_1 - bq_2)$$
Should the $V’$ terms be partial derivatives (with respect to $q_1$ and $q_2$ for $\dot{p}_{1}$ and $\dot{p}_{2}$, respectively?).

The notation is a little sloppy from a purely mathematical point of view (although common in physics) so it might be causing a little confusion.
To help clarify, it might help to use different letters for the potential in this equation:
$$
V(q_1, q_2) = f(a q_1 - b q_2)
$$
In other words, on the left hand side, $V$ is a function of two variables, while on the right hand side, $f$ is a function of one variable. Susskind uses the same letter for both functions (which is a common step in physics), but note that they are strictly different mathematical objects.
The other thing to remember is what the notation $f'(a q_1 - b q_2)$ means. It means to first evaluate the derivative of $f$ with respect to its argument, then plug in the value $a q_1 - b q_2$. In other words,
$$
f'(a q_1 - b q_2) = \frac{df}{dx}\Big|_{x=a q_1 - b q_2}
$$
Given these notational clarifications, I think it should hopefully be easy to see that, for example,
$$
p_1 = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_1} = - \frac{d f}{dx} \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1} = - a f'(a q_1 - b q_2)
$$
where $x=a q_1 - b q_2$.

They are partial derivatives. From the chain rule, we have
$$
\frac{\partial V(aq_1-bq_2)}{\partial q_1}= a V'(aq_1-bq_2),\\
\frac{\partial V(aq_1-bq_2)}{\partial q_2}= -b V'(aq_1-bq_2).
$$
For example
$$
\frac{\partial \sin(aq_1-bq_2)}{\partial q_1}= a \cos(aq_1-bq_2),\\
\frac{\partial \sin (aq_1-bq_2)}{\partial q_2}= -b \cos(aq_1-bq_2).
$$
Here, $V(x)= \sin(x)$ and  $V'(x)=\cos(x)$.

No. The notation means that the V on the RHS is a function only of one variable, and so its derivative is the simplest, one-variable derivative.
